# merge two data frames by index and column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two data frames, like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['v1'] = [5,7,2,4,9,7,2]
df1['v2'] = ["a1", 'nan', "a2", "a3", "a5", "a6", "a9"]

   v1   v2
0   5   a1
1   7  nan
2   2   a2
3   4   a3
4   9   a5
5   7   a6
6   2   a9
```

and

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame()
dfa['pc1'] = np.random.rand(5)
dfa['pc2'] = np.random.rand(5)
dfa['idx'] = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a6", "a9"]
df2 = dfa.set_index('idx')

          pc1       pc2
idx                    
a1   0.048725  0.050773
a2   0.289110  0.302272
a3   0.720966  0.663910
a6   0.021616  0.308114
a9   0.205923  0.583591
```

df1 has a column v2 that contains character values that match the index of df2. But it also has nan and may contains characters where no corresponding rownames in df2 exists.

I now want to merge these data frames to one, like this:

```
  v1    v2       pc1       pc2
0  5   a1   0.048725  0.050773
1  7  nan        nan       nan
2  2   a2   0.289110  0.302272
3  4   a3   0.720966  0.663910
4  9   a5        nan       nan
5  7   a6   0.021616  0.308114
6  2   a9   0.205923  0.583591
```

In `R` this is very easy using the `rownames_to_column(df2, "v2")` and
                   `left_join(df1, .)` functions.

But how can I do it in pandas ?

Comment: btw, the `set_index` call somehow complicates stuff. This is not needed and you can pass the join parameter for every frame separately. So, you can always avoid joining by index, if you use e.g. `reset_index()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do something like

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'v2', right_index=True, how = 'left')
```

this yields:

```
   v1   v2       pc1       pc2
0   5   a1  0.048725  0.050773
1   7  NaN       NaN       NaN
2   2   a2   0.28911  0.302272
3   4   a3  0.720966   0.66391
4   9   a5       NaN       NaN
5   7   a6  0.021616  0.308114
6   2   a9  0.205923  0.583591
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [37]: df1.merge(df2, right_index=True, left_on='v2', how='outer')
Out[37]:
   v1   v2       pc1       pc2
0   5   a1  0.252062  0.602530
1   7  nan       NaN       NaN
2   2   a2  0.328666  0.988321
3   4   a3  0.704342  0.809817
4   9   a5       NaN       NaN
5   7   a6  0.001230  0.602590
6   2   a9  0.635444  0.926872
```

---

```
In [33]: df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_on='v2', how='outer')
Out[33]:
        pc1       pc2  v1   v2
0  0.252062  0.602530   5   a1
2  0.328666  0.988321   2   a2
3  0.704342  0.809817   4   a3
5  0.001230  0.602590   7   a6
6  0.635444  0.926872   2   a9
1       NaN       NaN   7  nan
4       NaN       NaN   9   a5
```

Comment: thanks, why are the indices not ordered now, and how can I order the rows again by indices?

Comment: @spore234, in this case you want to put `df1` first - see updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.merge(df2.reset_index(), df1, left_on='idx', right_on='v2', how='outer').drop('idx', axis=1)


Output:

            pc1            pc2      v1    v2
  0      0.760966       0.059443    5     a1
  1      0.059443       0.984703    2     a2
  2      0.214868       0.677140    4     a3
  3      0.224410       0.037784    7     a6
  4      0.297342       0.341810    2     a9
  5        NaN            NaN       7     nan
  6        NaN            NaN       9     a5
```